# Dynamics CRM 2011 - change active directory

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-dynamics-crm

We have a Dynamics CRM 2011 installation and we want to change its active directory.
Where is the correct place to do that without re-installing the CRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if the two active directories has trusted relationships you just have to change in user settings the domain of the user. I do the same thing in this week and i based in that [support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930853/en-us). The support is for CRM 3.0 and 4.0 but i think you can replicate for 2011 version.